# ld: library not found for -lyoutube-ios-player-helper

Tags: ios, swift, linker, linker-errors, exit

I have the following error. How can I solve it?

[image: click here]

Comment: please add more details

Comment: please click to open the photo proplem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I solve it?

The error is *very simple*: you asked for your application to be linked with `libyoutube-ios-player-helper`, but have not provided such library anywhere the linker could find.

If this library does exist somewhere on your system, you need to add `-L/path/to/dir/where/libyoutube-ios-player-helper/resides`. If that library doesn't exist, you should remove `-lyoutube-ios-player-helper` from your command line.

Comment: Library dose exist but how i can input the file library how i can find the path

Comment: @user6552240 How do you *know* the library exists? The only way to know is to find it somewhere on your filesystem, and once you do *that*, you should know which directory the library is in.